# How to configure Vimeo-Service-module in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe, vimeo-api

Forgive me for my English

I am new in **PHP**. And I'm building a site using **Silverstripe** and trying to configure **Vimeo-Service-module**. I'd follow the steps from this link

https://github.com/r0nn1ef/Silverstripe-Vimeo-Service-module

I did everything that mentions in the article. And created a page in admin panel of **VimeoGallery** **page type** and set the parameters on **Videos** tab to grab the videos for display.

After created page, I visited my and clicked on video menu but then all I see is **no videos returned**. It is showing blank page and no any error messages.

Is that I've done anything wrong. Please guide me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That module is for an old version of silverstripe. Which version do you have?

Comment: Thanks for response micmania1. I've downloaded the latest version from the Silverstripe website. It is SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.6.

Comment: There's probably compatibility issues with the module. There is a way to add vimeo video's by default in the new version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mkI0H3J32Y

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I want to add all videos from the Vimeo account. Suppose I've register my account on Vimeo. And there I've created a channel  and in that 2-3 videos is there. That videos i want to show on that Silverstripe site.

Comment: @SandeepRoniyaar did you download the `master` branch or the [`2.0`](https://github.com/r0nn1ef/Silverstripe-Vimeo-Service-module/tree/2.0) branch of the SilverStripe Vimeo Service module? The master branch is for SilverStripe 2.4 and will not work for your 3.1.6 version. The 2.0 branch however is for SilverStripe 3.0 and may work for your version. It may require a few modifications.

Comment: Greetings @3dgo I did configure 2.0 branch of the Silverstripe Vimeo Service module in my project. But when I run dev/build it is showing error. 

    "Non-static method VimeoService::setAPIKey() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\wamp\www\Vimeo\mysite\_config.php on line 19."

You mentioned in the above post that it required some modification.Colud you please guide me what modification I have to do or what mistakes I have done.

Comment: Next opportunity I get I'll download it and have a look.

Comment: @SandeepRoniyaar, `VimeoService::setAPIKey()` won't work for the version of the module you have. Download the `master` branch and try again.

Comment: @Turnerj, I have downloaded the master branch from the https://github.com/r0nn1ef/Silverstripe-Vimeo-Service-module and SilverStripe-cms-v3.1.6 but it doesn't work. See above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I see the issue here. You are calling `VimeoService::setAPIKey()` however accessing the method like that is deprecated in the new version (the `2.0` branch - I was incorrect in my comment when I mentioned `master`) of the module.

The module instead uses the [Site Config in the CMS to set the API key and a few other settings](https://github.com/r0nn1ef/Silverstripe-Vimeo-Service-module/blob/2.0/code/VimeoSiteConfig.php).

Now just remove `VimeoService::setAPIKey()` from your `_config.php` file, run `/dev/build` and set the API key through the CMS.

**EDIT**

On line 142 of `VimeoGalleryPage.php`, there is a function called `flushCache`. Replace the code in that function with the following:

```
public function flushCache($persistent = true) {
    parent::flushCache($persistent);
    unset($this->_cachedVideos);
}
```

Basically, the code in the `2.0` branch for this function does not correctly extend the same named function in `SiteTree`.

Comment: @Turnej, I have already tried by removing "VimeoService::setAPIKey() and VimeoService::setSecretKey" but it doesn't work.It shows the following errors: "Declaration of VimeoGalleryPage::flushCache() should be compatible with SiteTree::flushCache($persistent = true) in C:\wamp\www\Vimeo\vimeoservice\code\VimeoGalleryPage.php on line 4". How I'll set API key through the CMS?

Comment: So my original answer was based on the error you left in the comments ("Non-static method VimeoService::setAPIKey() should not be called statically..."). I have updated my answer to also address the new issue you have raised.

Comment: Thanks @Turnej for your response, but after replacing the code with the function that you have mentioned in the above answer, it is showing Server error.

Comment: @Tunrej, It is showing only "
Server error

Sorry, there was a problem with handling your request.
". Not any other messages is showing.

Comment: That is unfortunate. You will need to modify your server configuration to enable showing more detailed errors before I can help more.

Comment: Thanks @Turnerj for your support. MySite is running now. I don't know what was the error. I restarted my app and it starts normally, may be server error. And it is showing the page type when I added a new page and it is asking "Video player ID (required when using the Javascript API.)". Is that it is asking api key. I did try with my api key but it is not working.Is there anything else I've to do. guide me..

Comment: `VideoPlayerID` is used if you were wanting to control the Vimeo player by javascript. You shouldn't need to specify anything if you are not going to use a JS API for the players.

Comment: So, how will I set the API key?cause it is showing no videos found.

Comment: [The API key is set in the SiteConfig.](https://github.com/r0nn1ef/Silverstripe-Vimeo-Service-module/blob/2.0/code/VimeoSiteConfig.php) If you have further questions, it is probably best to open another question on StackOverflow.